# General Q about using only [WebMethod] AJAX functions to handle requests.

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I am working on redesigning and streamlining the checkout process for an Ecommerce website using ASP.NET/C# into 1 page. (Currently, the website doesn't use any ASP controls)

Just for a little back info, the customer will be able to enter a shipping address, add a gift message, and select a shipping date per recipient while updating the backend with the correct information. I want this process to be elegant and pain free for customers to use.

Now I have created WebMethods that get called through AJAX requests that work correctly on previous features.

**My question is: 
Would it be an ok idea to submit ALL these requests through WebMethod AJAX calls, have it update the backend, and render the correct information to the user?**

I know it is doable but I just want to be sure that this is an ok approach to take. I have been looking at other JavaScript frame works that might help but am too unfamiliar with them to know if they would work or not.

Please let me know what you think and if you have other suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

You mentioned:

> an Ecommerce website using ASP.NET/C# into 1 page

If that is true, then you are talking about a single page web app. There are a couple of references to single page web apps here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463786.aspx

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

It's very common to do what you are talking about. Using AJAX to perform back-end processes and then update small pieces of the front end is key to making fluid, fast, and responsive web applications. That's mainly because smaller pieces of data are being sent through the network, and the UI is being updated in smaller segments. If architected correctly, single page web apps can provide a slick, intuitive web experience for clients and customers. Emphasis on "If architected correctly". So make sure to do your research.

There are several libraries out there that can help you, such as:

- jQuery
- jQueryUI
- Bootstrap
- Angularjs
- Sencha ExtJs
- Backbone
- Knockout

You don't have to use them, but they can save you a lot of time. At the very least, I would recommend using jQuery. Do some research and find out which one(s) will work best to fit your specific application.

Comment: Thank you for the information Matt and the list of frameworks. I already use Jquery & Bootstrap. I was reading into Ember.js but I will take a look at angular.js as well because it seems to be popular.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem in this approach, the good part about ajax WebMethod is that you will transfer only the important data to do the operation. its better and fast than use a updatePanel

We use a lot of ajax webMethod in our asp.net project and we never got problems with it :)

A good advice is looking for asp.net mvc, its better than asp.net web forms

Comment: Thank you for the reassurance Milton, I will stick with this approach then. I wish we could convert to MVC but unfortunately, when you're dealing with a website that was built in the ancient times (2004), It would be a giant project to convert (or so I think).